# Best way to edit EmPy files?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any structured text editor for *.em files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297744/best-way-to-edit-empy-files?/) by [calvertdw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29941/calvertdw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-17**:
I'm not sure that this is the appropriate site for this question as it's not a ROS question.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-07-17**:
This is not a ROS-specific question. You should ask your question of the EmPy developers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The are plugins for some editors which are able to highlight EmPy templates as well as the respective language the expanded templates generate:

- Atom [language-empy](https://atom.io/packages/language-empy)
- VSCode [vscode-empy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dirk-thomas.vscode-empy)

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [calvertdw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29941/calvertdw/) on 2018-07-18**:
Thank you! I figured you had something.